# How prevent deleting image from ActiveStorage by another user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I have User which have products. User can upload image for product using ActiveStorage. For uploading images I am using separate controller ImageController with only one action delete, and also I have route in my routes:

```
  delete "image/:id/purge", to: "images#delete", as: "purge_image"
```

So in my db I have ActiveStorage tables, User table and Product table. User has_many products and Product belongs_to User. As I understand, User does not have any connection to ActiveStorage table. How prevent deleting image by another User if he want to use direct route to delete image? Or how to find out which user uploaded image? I will be appreciate for your help.

Comment: _"User does not have any connection to ActiveStorage table"_ if there is no connection between a user and an image, how can you know which user uploaded which image? I would argue that you cannot. You need some connection. Therefore you will need to add a connection first.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is something like this in your controller

```
def delete
  ActiveStorage::Attachment
    .where(record_id: current_user&.product_ids)
    .find(params[:id])
    .purge
end
```

This way you will find attachments only in the scope of current user products

`find` method will raise 404 error if this user haven't such images

Or you can use some authorization gem (ActionPolicy, pundit, cancancan etc.)

Comment: Hello. So in such case we can find our attachment only among record ids of current user which are the same as product ids. I will try that. Thanks a lot.